# Is it possible to send a gmail email with the + sign alias as sender?

Tags: gmail, alias

A mobile network provider requires me to send an email from the exact address that I signed up with for their service. I used a gmail address with a + sign alias for that.

Example: email+providername@gmail.com

Is it possible to send an email from exactly that address from gmail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it as an additional email in gmail and verify it as a "send mail as" email. Then you should be able to send from it.

**Example Sending:**

Add email to gmail as additional emails. Example: `example+anything@gmail.com`

I just looked at my account to find the exact instructions for you.

1. `Gear` icon
2. `See All Settings` link
3. `Accounts` tab
4. `Add another email address` link
5. `Treat as an alias` checkbox is checked
6. Verify the email in gmail when you receive it.
7. Send mail as this alias when you go to send mail to the provider.

**Example Receiving:**

your email > `example@gmail.com`
alias > `example+anything@gmail.com`

You will receive email to the `example+anything@gmail.com` at the original email of `example@gmail.com`.